# python won't run this program; says there is a syntax error

Tags: python, syntax

```
n = int(input())
s = 1000000
a = []
for i in range(n):
  a.append(int(input())
for i in range(0,(n-16)):
  for k in range(15,(n-16)):
    if (a[i]*a[i+k]) <= s:
      s = a[i]*a[i+k]
print(s)
```

The program won't run. The colons are considered to be errors, as well as the 's = a[i]*a[i+k]' string. Need help!

Comment: The brackets are mismatched on the second input() line.

Comment: Oh gosh, thanks! I'm just starting out. Should pay more attention.

Comment: If you are new to a programming language, it might be a good idea to use an editor that can help you pointing out basic errors like this. It will save you so much time.

Comment: Thanks! I am, in fact, using one. But somtimes it points at things as errors even if they aren't errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should close the brackets on the second input

```
n = int(input())
s = 1000000
a = []
for i in range(n):
  a.append(int(input()) <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< here
for i in range(0,(n-16)):
  for k in range(15,(n-16)):
    if (a[i]*a[i+k]) <= s:
      s = a[i]*a[i+k]
print(s)
```